# PhpStorm remove port from localhost URL

Tags: phpstorm

When I run my files it takes me to: http://localhost:63342/leadmandist/index.php

I want it to take me to:http://localhost/leadmandist/index.php

How do I remove this `:63342` from the URL as it is causing a "Bad Gateway" error? I want this to apply to all of my files.

I tried removing the port in the settings but it won't allow an empty value and just reverts back to 63342.

I am using WAMPServer. If there is a better solution than what I want then I'd love to know.

Comment: Instead of leaving it empty, change to port 80.

Comment: Sort of similar question -- appeared in "Related" column after I have post my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31767353/783119

Comment: Changing it to port 80 did not resolve the issue - it literally just reverts it back to 63342.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are seeing there is PhpStorm's own simple built-in web server. If you want to use your own web server (Apache/IIS/nginx/whatever) then you have to tell IDE about it:

1. `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`
2. Create and configure new entry (`In Place` type should do; as long as your files are already located in a place where Apache will be able to serve them from)
3. The key here is to provide your desired URL here
4. Mark this entry as Default for this project
5. Now when you will use "Run" or "Open in Browser" the IDE will use URL defined there as a base for constructing full URLs.

Comment: Still goes to http://localhost:63342/leadmandist/index.php even after following your steps.

Comment: Also, "index.php" shows up under "Javascritp Debug" in the "Run/Debug Configurations" window.

Comment: @kjdion84 Then you did something wrong (or missed something, e.g. step #4) -- it's definitely works as I have been suggesting these steps on many occasions (quite a few answers on this site). Maybe try restarting your IDE. In any case: please post a screenshot with your deployment settings.

Comment: *"Also, "index.php" shows up under "Javascritp Debug" in the "Run/Debug Configurations" window"* Right now I do not see how it's related. Please explain.

Comment: It is related because when I select "Run index.php" it is taking me to the URL present in the Run/Debug Configurations. I want to use WAMPSERVER, not PhpStorm's built-in web server. There are several reasons for this - 1. speed. 2. convenience. 3. consistency. I know I can just visit the localhost URL directly through my broser but for the sake of convenience I wanted my URL to work directly through PhpStorm's "Run" option.

Comment: @kjdion84 You have small misunderstanding of how Run/Debug configurations work. Once it created, it remembers most of the settings( URL in particular) so it's consistent between runs and even machines (as they can be shared with team members). This means -- you have to either edit your exiting Run/Debug Configuration and change URL there or create new Configuration from scratch. Doing what I have described in my answer will not affect your **existing** Run/Debug Configurations -- only future ones.